# jQuery if/else statement CSS

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have an interesting problem that I don't understand. It's a simple jQuery if else statement, but it's not working. Why is it not working?

Code:

```
$("#div").click(function(){

    if ( $("#div2").css("background-image") === "url(img/image.png)") {
        alert('OK');
    }
    else {
        alert('NG');
    }

});
```

But when I change `.css("background-image") === "url(img/image.png)"`, for example, to `.css('position') === 'absolute'`, it's working.

Comment: What happens if you alert (or write/log/inspect) `$("#div2").css("background-image")`.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html you're checking and maybe the corresponding css?

Comment: thats weird, why would `.css('height') === 'absolute'` ever work?

Comment: oh, sorry its .css('position') === 'absolute' not .css('height') === 'absolute'.

Comment: @j08691 I tried == insted of === but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the right answer is to write the full path to the image. So, use `url(http://www.myhost.com/img/image.png)` instead of `url(img/image.png)` .

Answer (score 4):

There could be a subtle difference in the value; alert the value in the else statement to see what's going on. For example,

```
if ( $("#div2").css("background-image") === "url(img/image.png)") {
    alert('OK');
}
else {
    alert($("#div2").css("background-image"));
}
```

Comment: Yup, the `background-image` url gets a fully qualified path. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TKUET/

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that when the css loads, it is taking url(img/image.png) and turing that into http://www.somehost.com/img/image.png.  Thus, .css("background-image") would no longer equal "url(img/image.png)".

Instead of checking

```
.css('background-image') == 'url(img/Image.png)'
```

check

```
.css('background-image').indexOf("img/Image.png") != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting in the dark here, but "url(img/image.png)" should probably have single quotes around the argument to url() since that's the way the syntax goes for the CSS.

`"url('img/image.png')"`

Comment: Quoting the path is optional and both single and double quotes are fine.

Comment: Sure, both are fine when declaring the path in the stylesheet.  The question here, however, is: What does $("#div2").css("background-image") return?  A string with or without the single quotes.  This might be a browser dependent answer, so doing an indexOf, as Daniel suggests above, might be the safest way to go.

Comment: In Firefox at least, the full path is returned and enclosed in double quotes: `url("http://thesite.tld/path/to/image.png")` (see my fiddle above)